# How to set X11 conf file as symlink?

Tags: x11, xorg, configuration, symlink, x-server

Xorg doesn't interpret configuration file from neither `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*` nor `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/*` if said file is a symbolic link.

I would like to keep my custom configuration files for X11 versioned in `/home/username/.config/` and only link them to `xorg.conf.d` but can't seem to be able to achieve that and neither to find the problem.

xorg-server version: 1.20.9-2

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*` is supposed to be system-wide configuration, as it affects how the X server uses the hardware.

If you are using a GUI-style login, then the X server needs to start before login in order to display the login box. If your home directory is encrypted (e.g. using `pam_mount` or similar), then the home directory won't be readable yet when the X server needs to read its configuration.

On laptops and the like, the recommended strategy is usually to rely on autodetection for as much as possible, and let the desktop environment (or user's session startup, if using a "light" window manager instead of a "full" GNOME or KDE desktop environment) handle the user-specific configuration.

In a true multi-user system, having write access to X server configuration as a regular user would be a security risk: the user with the access to configuration files can tell the X server to load arbitrary modules (conceivably also malicious ones) and have them run as root. In a personal laptop/workstation this might not be a concern.

Personally, I use `etckeeper` (might be in your distribution's package collection!) to keep essentially my entire `/etc` directory tree under Git version control (with configurable exceptions). `etckeeper` also tracks file permissions, unlike regular Git. Since those files can contain security-sensitive material like passwords, the primary repository in `/etc/.git` is writeable to root only. But for backup purposes, I'm pushing a copy of the repository to another (secure) location, whose permissions I can set as I see fit. You might consider something similar.

Comment: I don't have a login manager and am running a window manager (herbstluftwm). Since my install is on BTRFS I don't feel the need to version `/etc` and the only settings that I want to keep in my dotfiles repo are libinput stuff. Copying my _*.conf_ files to either `*/xorg.conf.d` works yet symbolic linking, as root, does not and I fail to understand why.